# Dynamic picklist values in standard relatedlist

Tags: custom-field, picklist, related-list, dynamic

The problem occurs in the opportunity related list of a custom object.
I have create a custom picklist on the custom object with dynamic values.

Eg. 
You select the product eg a pullover and you get the list of colors/size.
The custom object works. It can be saved and retrieve.

If I add the custom picklist on the relatedlist columns, It doesn't show the value selected but the ordinal index of the value choosed.

Is there any way to retrieve the real value without rewriting all the opportunity page ?

Thanks,
Best regards,
HP42

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: can u add a screenshot of what you are referring to and highlight what's ur issue.. it will help us to suggest you some solutions better.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you created a custom object as a custom picklist.
Also, you added a custom lookup field on your product object linked to this custom picklist object.

If you want to be able to choose the picklist field to show on your related list, you must change the field type of the lookup field to a master-detail relationship.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution. It is not perfect but it works. During change of color or size, I copy the value in a text field. The text field is shown on the related list.

Thanks for help,
Best regards,
HP